# Glitchy rope physics(processing 2.2.1)

Tags: processing

I made something to simulate a rope and it glitches out when the thing being held by the rope is under the thing holding the rope. This works when not in a for loop and its just one segment but i want to be able to simulate multiple segments.

code:

```java
//Declaring variables
int linkCount = 3;
float Rotation = 0;
float R = radians(Rotation);
float x[] = new float[linkCount];
float y[] = new float[linkCount];
float xVel[] = new float[linkCount];
float yVel[] = new float[linkCount];
float ropeLength = 50;
float velMX;
float velMY;
float spring = 1;
void setup() {
  size(1280, 500, P3D);
  stroke(0);
  fill(0);
}
void draw() {
  background(255);
  // Updating velocitys
  for(int i=1; i < linkCount; i++) {
      x[i] = x[i] + xVel[i];
      y[i] = y[i] + yVel[i];
  }
  // The two lines below are not needed and will most likely will be used in the futre
  velMX =  pmouseX - mouseX;
  velMY = pmouseY - mouseY;
  // Setting the start of the rope to the mouse
  x[0] = mouseX;
  y[0] = mouseY;
//  if(mousePressed) {
    calcRopes();
//  }
}
void calcRopes() {
  for(int i = 1; i < linkCount; i++) {
  // Getting a radian that points toward the last subrope
  R = atan2(-(x[i] - x[i-1]), -(y[i] - x[i-1]));
  // Drawing the rope
  line(x[i], y[i], x[i - 1], y[i - 1]);
  // If the segment is farther than the rope length it moves it inside the rope length based on the R radian
  if(dist(x[i], y[i], x[i - 1], y[i - 1]) > ropeLength) {
  x[i] = x[i] + ((dist(x[i], y[i], x[i - 1], y[i - 1]) - (ropeLength)) * sin(R));
  y[i] = y[i] + ((dist(x[i], y[i], x[i - 1], y[i - 1]) - (ropeLength)) * cos(R));
  //      xVel[i] =  ((dist(x[i], y[i], x[i-1], y[i-1]) - (ropeLength + 10)) * sin(R));
  //      yVel[i] =  ((dist(x[i], y[i], x[i-1], y[i-1]) - (ropeLength + 10)) * cos(R));
  }
  }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Don't use variables to set your screen size, processing 2.2.1 doesn't like that and Processing 3 doesn't even allow that.

Secondly:

```
  line(x[i], y[i], x[i--], y[i--]);
```

Statements like this from calcRopes() will cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Why are you using i-- for? Everytime you use that, i is decremented once. So starting with i=2, your value for i becomes -1 after the "line(x[i], y[i], x[i--], y[i--]);"

Edit:
This worked for me but I think it needs some adjustment still.

```
int linkCount = 10;
float Rotation = 0;
float R = radians(Rotation);
float x[] = new float[linkCount];
float y[] = new float[linkCount];
float xVel[] = new float[linkCount];
float yVel[] = new float[linkCount];
float ropeLength = 100;
float velMX;
float velMY;
float spring = 1;
void setup() {
  size(1280, 500); //CHANGED THIS***********************
}
void draw() {
  stroke(0);
  fill(0);
  background(255);
  for (int i=0; i < linkCount; i++) {
    x[i] = x[i] + xVel[i];
    y[i] = y[i] + yVel[i];
  }
  velMX =  pmouseX - mouseX;
  velMY = pmouseY - mouseY;
  x[1] = mouseX;
  y[1] = mouseY;
  //  if(mousePressed) {
  calcRopes();
  //  }
}

//REPLACED ALL i-- with i-1 (just to see if it works)***********************
void calcRopes() {
  for (int i = 1; i < linkCount; i++) {
    if (i<x.length && i<y.length) {
      R = atan2(-(x[i] - mouseX), -(y[i] - mouseY));
      line(x[i], y[i], x[i-1], y[i-1]);
      if (dist(x[i], y[i], x[i - 1], y[i - 1]) > ropeLength) {
        xVel[i] =  ((dist(x[i], y[i], x[i-1], y[i-1]) - (ropeLength - 1)) * sin(R)) / spring;
        yVel[i] =  ((dist(x[i], y[i], x[i-1], y[i-1]) - (ropeLength - 1)) * cos(R)) / spring;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was using it to link to the last line, ill find a way to decrement it without changing the variable.

Comment: Thanks for the help, now i need to figure out how to make it look alot more like a rope

Comment: @8o7wer Thats what I thought but as I said, it decreases everytime you use i--. Isn't it i-1 what you wish to use? Or do you really want to use i-- until it is 0? In that case put a simple counter, make it equal to i and decrement it only until it is equal to 0. Another problem with using i-- is, that would be an infinite loop even if you checked for i==0 because it would never be i==linkCount.

Comment: @8o7wer no problem! It looks like a nice idea. I don't think it will take much more time to complete it.  You can also consider a static rope length and have that length divided to a certain number of smaller lines. Also, you might want to use size(1280, 500, P3D) to use the power of GPU with which you can create much more accurate movement via more number of sub-lines.

Comment: yes that is what i wanted, but now im getting a glitch when the rope grabs itself?

Answer (score 0):

I found out this line:

```
R = atan2(-(x[i] - x[i-1]), -(y[i] - x[i-1]));
```

Had a error which made it miscalculate the radian

```
R = atan2(-(x[i] - x[i-1]), -(y[i] - y[i-1]));
```

Is what I wanted.
Im still having issues with making it look realistic but i can solve that myself.